# Is it possible to deploy my Wordpress blog on my another React/NextJS site e.g. mydomain.com/blog?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, url-routing, next.js, wordpress-rest-api

I have a WordPress Blog and a ReactJS/NextJS website. Currently, I have only **1 domain** with myself and the WordPress blog is hosted on a different server. I want to deploy my WordPress blog under same domain which currently includes my React?NextJS site. I don't want to create a subdomain as it is not useful for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [proxy middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-proxy-middleware) and redirect any request that goes to `/blog` in your nextjs app through the proxy to your blog server.

Comment: I don't want to redirect as it will won't be good for SEO, any other way ?

Comment: what do you mean by redirect? it is redirecting but your dns stays still because your apps proxying to your blog.

Comment: The problem with this is whenever I try to open .. lets say a article on mywordpress.com/article1, it changes the URL in ReactJS app as well and I don't want the URL to change.

Comment: No, using proxy redirect won't change your URL. For example your domain is ABC.com, and your article is in wordpress.com/article1, by using proxy you'll have ABC.com/article1 or you can even add slug like ABC.com/article/1, its up to you to control the url.. URL will be changed if you redirect from your frontend.

Comment: It depends on this code I think:

app.use(
  "/",
  createProxyMiddleware({
    target: "https://mywordpress.com",
    changeOrigin: true,
  })

So in this I need to specify this code for everypage.. thats the problem

Comment: you can use regex but your reactjs app still need to know which url exists on your blog server..
other option IMHO just define specific route to help your reactjs app only redirect that route to your blog.. e.g: yourwebsite.com/article/new-info. in your react app `app.use("/article/:title")`